# String or Number Codes for Field Values - What's the Best Practice?

Tags: database, encoding, schema, field

In an application (in my case, a web application with database, server, and frontend layers), if you have a field that has a limited number of possible values, what's the best way to represent that on the database?

For example, say we have an employee status field that can have the following values:

- Active
- Terminated
- Leave of Absence

This field will be transferred between tiers, and logic done on the values for different purposes (say to highlight with different colors on the web page).

So what's the best way to store these values so that **a)** bugs are less likely but **b)** is still easy for developers to use?

Should the value be stored as an enumeration (1, 2, 3) corresponding to the different status, or as plain strings, or as some shortened value with no whitespace, like (ACT, TER, LOA), or is this purely a matter of preference? I was leaning towards numbers as you won't run into spelling mistakes, but that has the tradeoff of obfuscation.

Tag suggestions for this topic appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think both have PROs and CONS.
Using Numbers:

```
1. Lesser Size 
2. Performance
3. Lesser Error 
4. Easy To Code
```

On the Other hand, when using IDs one major issue would be every application that needs to interact with DB need to know this IDs and its meanings.Primary Example any Reporting tools. Of course, we can negate this impact by creating a definition table for each of such object types. I.e a table with only two columns ID, DESCR and then a simple joint will be sufficient.

Using Strings:

```
1. Easy to remember 
2. Easy for all other Systems directly talking to DB
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. If it's just systems, then numbers are probably better, or if it's just one system where you have to translate, then numbers are fine. But with 2 or more, it might not be worth the small guard against typos.

Comment: But as mentioned above we can always negate that imapct by creating simple definition tables which in my point of view is still more better than storing strings. One more issue will be when u want to query by these tags , index Strings will be big overhead.